# Downgrade Comctl32.ocx

Tags: vb6

I'm in need of downgrading from comctl32.ocx v1.4 to v1.3.
I have copied the dll, ocx and oca from a pc with the v1.3.
Unregistered the ocx and registered again but it didn't work v1.4 persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by  "1.4 persists" you mean that your project is still trying to use 1.4, this is because it is referenced as 1.4 in the *.vbp file.

if that is the case:

- open your project (*.vbp file) with notepad and change the 1.4 to 1.3.

This will make the project use the correct dll version you want it to use. i've had a similar problem with projects that i was working on with a colleague, since our versions of a particular dll are different. Changing this value before opening allows us both to work on it (bit of a hassle but reasons for it). hope it helps.